# Bezier Curved Line between 2 Waypoints with Heading

Tags: lua

I'm working currently on an Navigation System for an Aircraft and I have 3 waypoints with their heading given.Now I want to draw a Bezier Curved Line between these 2 Waypoints and I already know how the Curved Line should look but I can't figure out a good formula for that.
[Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1afk.png)

Answer (score 0):

See my recent [post](https://brianolive.github.io/programming/Bezier-Fibonacci-and-Newton/) where I did this in Lua. More importantly, my source on the how-to’s  of Bezier curves is [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/). There’s plenty of example code at that link (not necessarily in Lua, but the math is generally applicable. Take some time to read and understand even the first few core functions, and you should be good to go. If you get stuck, come back with specific questions and your code at that point, and I (and others, I’m sure) could help.

Comment: Okay I read the article and understood the most of it :) I already have 2 predefined functions given from the framework that I'm using: drawBezierLineQAdaptive ( number x1 , number y1 , number x2 , number y2 ,
number x3 , number y3 , Color color ) which draws a quadratic Bezier Line with x1 as startpoint and x2 as control and x3 as end point.And I have .drawBezierLineC ( number x1 , number y1 , number x2 , number y2 , number
x3 , number y3 , number x4 , number y4 , number parts , Color color ) which does the same but only with 2 control points.But I didn't understand how to calculate

Comment: I see. So it seems you have functions already to calculate Bezier curves, but you need a curve to go through predetermined points, and you don't know what control points to pass into the function that would create a curve through those points. Code I've written doesn't do that either. I also go from control points to curve coordinates - not the other way around. I'll think through the problem later (at work now!) and see if its easy to calculate.

Comment: Could you find something related ? :)